# Restoring from files, not backup

Tags: backup

My oneplus2 recently got stuck in a bootloop after years of usage. Despite all my attempts of flashing the rom again with or without root + custom kernel, it didn't boot. So I moved all my internal storage (every folder) to my pc by connecting it via usb while it was in recovery mode. Then I factory reset, still didn't work. I had to wipe data (not internal storage) as well then flash the rom after to get the phone to boot. My question is, can I restore app data (and potentially the apps as well) ? The rom and android version is the same, Oxygen OS 3.6.1

Comment: I assume that in recovery mode you only had access to the so called "sd-card" section, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe it was the sd-card section. Since I only want to restore non-system apps, that shouldn't be a problem. But I just don't know how.

Comment: If you only have the "sd-card" section you have a problem because the real app data is stored in /data/data. On the sd-card section usually only  large non-critical data is stored because it is public.